# Mac Facetime Screen Sharing Broken

Tags: mac, apple-silicon, menu-bar, facetime, screen-sharing

I have a **Macbook Air** with an M1 processor, and for the past few software updates (currently 14.2.1), whenever I share my screen, **Im unable to stop sharing it until I end the Facetime call**. Even then, the sharing screen notification still appears in the top right in the menu bar and **I'm unable to share my screen for future Facetime calls** unless I restart my laptop (thus removing the problem). Is this a known issue, and is there a way to fix it minus restarting my laptop?
[image: Facetime Screen Sharing Broken]